# How to know if table has any deleted row?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with lots of brand names in it.
I want to control if it has any changes before my process.

So I use

```
select max(track_update_time) from brands limit 1
```

When I delete a record there is changes but I can't know it by asking update time.

I try to create an after delete trigger with:

```
update brands set max(track_update_time) = now()
```

but it locks table on delete and give error on trigger.

How can I learn if table has any updated or deleted record?

Comment: You could use triggers to maintain a separate auditing table, and inspect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the update time any more because it is deleted. So you have either only MARK the row as deleted using an additional row (and still **leaving** it in the DB).

If only the latest time of deletion of **any** row is of relevance, you simply could store it in a separate, new table.

And if the same applies for updates, store these in this table, too, and delete the current update time row entirely (saving storage space)...

Comment: i cant change tables design, so i have to find a way to know if a table has any changes. i have triggers on insert and on update. if it has a new record i can see it by its creation time. if it has any update i can see it with update time. my problem is, if any record deleted i cant know it with creation or update time field or any min and max query

Comment: Sorry for late answer - somehow missed the comment... If it still helps: If you cannot modify existing tables, but at least add new ones, you could add a new table (e. g. 'history') with those attributes of the original table you still need. Deletion time of the original entry would be creation time of the entry in the history table. If you cannot even create new tables, I don't see a way of not losing the information once the trigger has completed.